# Current flow in full wave bridge rectifier during negative half wave

Tags: bridge-rectifier, waveform

I was watching a video on full wave bridge rectifiers and was wondering why the current flows in the direction of the green arrow (+ to point C) during the negative half wave, instead of going in the direction of the pink arrow to the resistor?

[image]

Comment: The pink arrow follows the path from the bridge rectifier's negative output to the load, current never flows that way. Those crossing lines are not connected together btw, the gap in the vertical line indicates that.

Comment: ohh ok I get it now, I misunderstood the diagram, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The negative cycle conducts thru D1,D3, and +ve cycle thru D2,D4.

So the green and your pink arrow are the same current.